# Mostrar ventana de progreso con SelfExtractor (Ionic.Zip)

Tags: c#, zip

Estoy desarrollando un Setup para unas aplicaciones y uso SelfExtractor para descomprimir los archivos y acto seguido ejecutar el programa que instala y configura la aplicación a través de `PostExtractCommandLine`.

El problema que tengo, es que no encuentro la forma de poder visualizar una ventana de progreso de cuando se están descomprimiendo los archivos, lo único que he conseguido es que me aparezca la lista de los archivos que se están descomprimiendo, pero no informa de cuanto queda para terminar (en % o en tiempo).

Mi código:

```
private static void createSetup(string sVersion, string sModule, string sSetupExeName, 
    string sDescription, string sPathIn, string sPathOut, 
    string PostExtractCommandLineParams, string[] sInterfaces, string sInterfaceFile, 
    string[] sLanguages, string sLanguage)
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    string nameComponentProduct = sSetupExeName.Replace(".exe", "");

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Starting " + sModule + "-" + sSetupExeName + "-" + 
        PostExtractCommandLineParams + "-" + sLanguage);

    oFvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(sPathIn, sSetupExeName));
    SelfExtractorSaveOptions options = new SelfExtractorSaveOptions
    {
        //AdditionalCompilerSwitches = "",
        Copyright = String.Format(oFvi.LegalCopyright, P.Year, P.Company),
        DefaultExtractDirectory = "",
        Description = oFvi.FileDescription,
        ExtractExistingFile = ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently,
        FileVersion = new Version(P.Version),
        Flavor = SelfExtractorFlavor.ConsoleApplication,
        IconFile = "icono.ico",
        PostExtractCommandLine = (oFvi.OriginalFilename + " " +  
            PostExtractCommandLineParams).Trim(),
        ProductName = oFvi.ProductName,
        ProductVersion = oFvi.ProductVersion,
        Quiet = false,
        RemoveUnpackedFilesAfterExecute = true,
        SfxExeWindowTitle = ""
    };

    if (sLanguages != null)
    {
        string[] split = sLanguage.Split(new Char[] { '_' });
        string lang = split[0];
        string region = split[1];
        ci = new CultureInfo(lang + "-" + region);

        options.Description = String.Format(oFvi.FileDescription, P.Version, 
            ci.EnglishName);
        string sLang = sLanguage.Substring(3);
        if (sLang == "US") sLang = "EN";
        sPathOut = Path.Combine(sPathOut, "NombreApp_" + sModule + "_" + sLang + ".exe");
    }
    else
        sPathOut = Path.Combine(sPathOut, "NombreApp_" + sModule + ".exe");

    string DefaultExtractDirectory = Path.Combine(P.PathTmp, nameComponentProduct);
    if (Directory.Exists(DefaultExtractDirectory))
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(DefaultExtractDirectory, true);

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.StatusMessageTextWriter = System.Console.Out;
        zip.AddDirectory(sPathIn, "");
        if (sLanguages != null)
            zip.Comment = String.Format(oFvi.Comments, ci.EnglishName, PV.Version);
        else
            zip.Comment = String.Format(oFvi.Comments, P.Version);
        options.Description = sDescription + " " + sVersion;
        options.DefaultExtractDirectory = DefaultExtractDirectory;
        options.SfxExeWindowTitle = String.Format("Extracting {0} ...", 
            options.Description);
        zip.RemoveSelectedEntries("log/*");
        zip.RemoveSelectedEntries("*.pdb");
        if (sLanguages != null)
        {
            DefaultExtractDirectory = Path.Combine(P.PathTmp, 
                Path.Combine(nameComponentProduct, sLanguage));
            options.PostExtractCommandLine = sSetupExeName + " " + sLanguage;
            foreach (string sLanguage2 in sLanguages)
                if (sLanguage != sLanguage2)
                    zip.RemoveSelectedEntries("*pk_" + sLanguage2 + ".zip");
        }
        if (sInterfaces != null)
        {
            foreach (string sInterfaz in sInterfaces)
                if (sInterfaz != sInterfaceFile)
                    zip.RemoveSelectedEntries("*" + sInterfaz);
        }
        zip.SaveSelfExtractor(sPathOut, options);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("END.");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

Lo que mas se ha acercado al resultado que busco es cambiar la opción de `Flavor` en el `SelfExtractorSaveOptions`:

`Flavor = SelfExtractorFlavor.ConsoleApplication`: Me muestra la consola con la lista de archivos que va descomprimiendo, pero no me muestra tiempos ni % completado, que es lo que busco.

`Flavor = SelfExtractorFlavor.WinFormsApplication`: Me muestra la interfaz del usuario, con las opciones de extracción y un botón para ejecutar la extracción, cosa que no me interesa, lo que busco es que sea automático y me muestre el progreso (ya que algunos Zips tardan un tiempo en descomprimir y puede parecer que se bloquea la aplicación).

También está la opción `Quiet`, si la pongo en `True` se ocultan las ventanas, por eso la tengo en `False`.

Comment: No he usado esa librería,pero creo que hay dos opciones para crear archivos auto-extraibles, uno con Gui,y otro sin Gui. Te sale gui a ti cuando intentas extraer los archivos?

Comment: @Pikoh Acabo de editar para responderte a lo que preguntas, a ver si eso te sirve.

Comment: Vale, ya veo. Quieres que muestre progreso, pero que no tenga un GUI como tal. Esto me parece que por defecto no vas a poder conseguirlo. Veo dos opciones, o buscar otra librería que sea mas flexible, o crear tu propio auto instalador, aunque eso puede ser mas complicado. Tienes el código fuente de la librería disponible, mira como se genera el autoinstalador y prueba a modificarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución al problema que planteo:

Mirando el [Source Code](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Zip/ZipFile.SaveSelfExtractor.cs) de `DotNetZip` he visto que, configurando las `SelfExtractorSaveOptions` como `Flavor = SelfExtractorFlavor.WinFormsApplication` y añadiendo que `Quiet = true` la aplicación muestra una ventana con barras de progreso las cuales no son interactivas con el usuario, es decir, sólo son visibles y no se puede interactuar con los controles del formulario.

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
oFvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(sPathIn, sSetupExeName));
SelfExtractorSaveOptions options = new SelfExtractorSaveOptions
{
    //AdditionalCompilerSwitches = "",
    Copyright = String.Format(oFvi.LegalCopyright, P.Year, P.Company),
    DefaultExtractDirectory = "",
    Description = oFvi.FileDescription,
    ExtractExistingFile = ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently,
    FileVersion = new Version(P.Version),
    Flavor = SelfExtractorFlavor.WinFormsApplication,
    IconFile = "icono.ico",
    PostExtractCommandLine = (oFvi.OriginalFilename + " " +  
        PostExtractCommandLineParams).Trim(),
    ProductName = oFvi.ProductName,
    ProductVersion = oFvi.ProductVersion,
    Quiet = true,
    RemoveUnpackedFilesAfterExecute = true,
    SfxExeWindowTitle = ""
};
```